# Undefined function validation_errors - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

After following the CodeIgniter tutorial for a form (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html), I can't for the life in me get it to work.

All I seem to be getting is: Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_errors() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test_f/application/views/pages/contact_us.php on line 1

I'm using the latest version of CodeIgnitor (2.1.4)

**Controller**

```
<?php
class Form extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('pages/contact_us');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('pages/formsuccess');
    }
}
  }
?>
```

**View**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>
```

**Routes**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Where does your 'Form' controller sit in your site hierarchy - also what url are you hitting?

Comment: I'm running this locally. Here is the hierarchy: http://d.pr/i/BReY

Comment: What's inside your .htaccess? Usually it should be in the root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with your routes.  It appears you are routing everything to a controller called `pages`.

If you remove the `(:any)` route, then hit your form controller by going to:

index.php/form

or

add the following route before `(:any)`

```
$route['form'] = "form";
```

Then try again.

Comment: Great, that got it working, thank you. How come it goes to form and not contact_us though? Because the controller is called 'form'? And how do I prevent the error showing when I go to 'contact_us'.

Comment: yes, by default it will route to <controller>/<action> so /form will call the method index on the Form controller class. /form/blah will call the method blah on the Form controller class.

Comment: I've just changed the form.php to contact_us.php so I can use that url, but I seem to be getting the same error whenever I go to 'contact_us' - any ideas?

Comment: What do your routes look like now?  Also, have you renamed your class definition to Contact_us ?

Comment: $routes['contact_us'] = "contact_us"; here is my contact_us.php controller: http://d.pr/i/TBkm

Comment: is that your entire routes.php file?

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo in my answer.  It should be $route[] not $routes[]

Comment: Ahh I see, no problem. Now I'm getting this error: http://d.pr/i/Zs3b - I've only installed the default CodeIgnitier files, do I need to install additional libraries?

Comment: did you just do a find and replace?? I suspect you are now trying to load a helper called contact_us instead of the form helper.

Comment: Ahh stupid me! I got it working. Thank you very much for all your help!